# Method definition for 'initWithName...' not found. Error

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I have a NSObject class in Xcode and the *@implementation* line is giving me an error; *Method definition for 'initWithName:tutorID:tutorPhone:tutorEmail:' not found.*

My .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TutorsItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tutorName;
@property (nonatomic) int tutorID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tutorPhone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tutorEmail;


- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)tutorName tutorID:(int)tutorID tutorPhone:(NSString *)tutorPhone tutorEmail:(NSString *)tutorEmail;

@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "TutorsItem.h"

@implementation TutorsItem

@synthesize tutorName = tutorName;
@synthesize tutorID = tutorID;
@synthesize tutorPhone = tutorPhone;
@synthesize tutorEmail = tutorEmail;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tutorName = tutorName;
        self.tutorID = tutorID;
        self.tutorPhone = tutorPhone;
        self.tutorEmail = tutorEmail;

    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: definition or implementation?

Comment: The error is **definition** @Wain

Comment: Why does your implementation method not match your interface method at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you are clear what people are try to tell you in your .h you have the following line of code

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)tutorName tutorID:(int)tutorID tutorPhone:(NSString *)tutorPhone tutorEmail:(NSString *)tutorEmail;
```

but in your .m file you have this...

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
```

As you can see the 2 lines of code don't match, the compiler expects you to have a method in the .m file with the same name as you've defined in the .h. So to get rid of the error your .m file would need to have the following

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)tutorName tutorID:(int)tutorID tutorPhone:(NSString *)tutorPhone tutorEmail:(NSString *)tutorEmail
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tutorName = tutorName;
        self.tutorID = tutorID;
        self.tutorPhone = tutorPhone;
        self.tutorEmail = tutorEmail;

    }

    return self;
}
```

As others have also pointed out its not a good idea to have your parameter names to be the same as your properties, it just adds to confusion. The same goes for your `@synthesize`

This...

```
@synthesize tutorName = tutorName;
```

Might as well be this...

```
@synthesize tutorName;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am kind of new to objective c so thanks for dumbing it down :) I'm no longer at my computer but I will try this asap.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your .m file to:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)tutorName tutorID:(int)tutorID tutorPhone:(NSString *)tutorPhone tutorEmail:(NSString *)tutorEmail{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tutorName = tutorName;
        self.tutorID = tutorID;
        self.tutorPhone = tutorPhone;
        self.tutorEmail = tutorEmail;

    }

    return self;
}
```

The header of the function in .m file only included the subtitle, and not tutorName , tutorId and so on.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: By the way, I would probably change your @synthesize variable names or change the variable names in the initWithName function since they collide.

Answer (score 0):

`Method defenition not found` is not an ERROR, it's a WARNING. And you get it cause you did not provide the definition for your method inside `@implementation` section. You can still compile and run your code, but if you try to call this method your app will crash. Simply provide the definition and this warning will vanish

And btw get rid of this:

```
    self.tutorName = tutorName;
    self.tutorID = tutorID;
    self.tutorPhone = tutorPhone;
    self.tutorEmail = tutorEmail;
```

inside `- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle` because what you do there makes no sense. What you do there is assign variable values to themselves

Answer (score 0):

The report is not an error it's a warning (unless you've enabled "warnings are errors"). It's a common warning when your @interface declares a method that your @implementation doesn't provide.

At @Wain comments, you have an init method with a very different signature in your implementation; did you intend for it to match the signature that you defined, or did you plan to provide two initializers? It's fine to have a method that doesn't appear in your @interface, but it's expected that everything presented in your @interface is intended to have an implementation as well.

Comment: Yes it is a warning, sorry. But how do I fix it?

Comment: To fix it... provide the missing method or change the interface definition to match the method you already have :)

Comment: Ok, I found the typo. Title is supposed to be tutorName and subtitle is tutorPhone. Will that fix it?

Comment: No its more than that. Take a look at the FULL interface for initWithName and compare it to the implementation; after the initial name they're no longer identical -- make them identical to remove the warning. Your interface declares `initWithName:tutorId:tutorPhone:tutorEmail:`... the implementation needs to match on all accounts.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, I'm no longer at my computer so I cannot test. I will get back to you tomorrow. But that you very much.